# Exact usage of Response.RedirectPermanent

Tags: asp.net

I read many blogs, but I cannot understand the exact usage of `Response.RedirectPermanent`.       Is it relevant to SEO only, or it is useful for site performance as well?

Comment: This question is, I think, I bit too broad.  Stack Overflow is for getting help with specific problems you face.  Not so much for researching broad topics like SEO and the semantics of various redirects.

Comment: it's a helper method for doing 301 redirects, but agree with 
jadarnel27, what are 301 redirects and what they are used for is not question for SO. You should ask that question on webmasters.stackexchange.com, voting to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand, I can use RedirectPermanent only when I need to tell SEO that I removed a page and I got a new one instead of.

lets say that I have a page called "page1.aspx", and  google cached it in his database search, now if I changed the page1.aspx or I removed it, then I need to put the Response.RedirectPermanent("Page2.aspx) in the page load of Page1.aspx, so that google next time will know that Page1.aspx has become Page2.aspx

and it has nothing to do with site performance

[this article might be helpful to make you understand the usage](http://www.haiders.net/post/ResponseRedirectPermanent.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`Response.RedirectPermanent` is a URL redirection/ forwarding. You can get correct reasons at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection